# Changing default file permissions for group?

Tags: files

I'm not super familiar with the permissions structure in Drupal 7 so I'm not sure if this is actually an Apache question or a Drupal question.

I have a style.css file in /sites/all/themes/mytheme/css/ that I need to edit via FTP. That css folder also contains files that are edited via the Omega Tools UI. It appears that each time I use the UI to change style information, Drupal changes the owner of the css folder from ftpuser to www and gives it permissions 754 (group cannot write).

I am okay with the owner changing to www but I need to be able to edit my style.css file via FTP, so I need permissions to be 774. Is there a way I can set a default permissions structure on a folder or on Drupal in general that sets permissions to 774 instead of 754 whenever the system changes the owner of a folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe Drupal or Omega will be setting the default permissions to 754, more likely it's a default that your webhost has configured.  Things I would check would be:

- If you upload a file as ftpuser, does it default to 754?  If so, then they have a default permission set to 754.  You could contact the host to see if they are able to change that.
- If you manually create a file using PHP, does the file get created at 754? If so, same as above.
- If they're created at something other than 754, then it's likely Omega or Drupal that is doing that, but again I don't believe that's the case.

In any event, I've successfully gotten around this problem for many users by integrating a web-based file manager like [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce), which allows you to manage files without using FTP.